# C# - How to check if object of a type needs to be constructed?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, reflection

*(I'm sorry if duplicate, I'm not sure if to check for nullable or for primitives or whatever)*

I'm creating arrays of objects of a variable Type. It can be `int`, `string`, `Point` or `MyCustomClass` (probably no enums though, but they are same as `int` right ?).

---

**Input:** Type of array elements.

**Black box:** Check if type **NEEDS** to be constructed. Create array and if needs contruction create each element (with default values, because they don't matter at this time). Constructor must be parameterless ( -> fail function) but treat string as special type.

**Output:** `object` (runtime type of it is either `int[]` or `string[]` or `Point[]` etc.)

---

The problem I'm facing is that I create array full of `null`. Well primitives and structs work well I get `int[]` with no problem but classes result in "`null[]`".

---

What I have so far (not sure if I caught them all):

```
public object createArray(Type arrayElementType, int arrayLength)
{
    Array a = Array.CreateInstance(arrayElementType, arrayLength);
    if (!arrayElementType.IsPrimitive) // correct would be: if (!arrayElementType.IsValueType)
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++)
            a.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(arrayElementType), j);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve. Let's take `string` for example - you apparently want an array of non-null string references, but what should the contents of those strings be?

Comment: @JonSkeet Content doesn't matter. They just mustn't be null.

Comment: Can you show some code regarding this?

Comment: @mini-me: But something's got to make a decision about how to construct the objects. `string` doesn't have any parameterless constructors, for example - unless you're going to special-case it, how would you know what arguments to pass to the constructor? What would you do for a parameter of type `FileStream`? If you have a fixed set of classes you want to handle, that's one thing - doing it for *all* classes is a different matter.

Comment: What if the only constructor for `MyCustomClass` requires two object instances of `MyCustomClass1` and `MyCustomClass2`? And those, in turn, have further dependencies?

Comment: Maybe if you told us how you were planning to *use* this array, we might offer better suggestions. At the moment, this feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever "XY problme", "don't reinvent the wheel" and "premature optimization" comments are nothing more than **annoying**! Stop that!

Comment: @mini-me - whilst people continue to try to do odd or bizarre things without offering a context for it, it's always worth asking them to stop, take a step back, paint a bigger picture, and possible not end up build a Rube-Goldberg solution to what may turn out to be a problem that may be solved far more simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty here is in the *creationing the instances*; it's quite easy to find out whether instances will be created on array allocation: just check *default(T)* value. But how can we create an instance manually? What if your class has, say, five constructors?
In the code below, I create the instance if its class has a *default constructor* which is *public* and has *no arguments*.

```
public static T[] CreateArray<T>(int size) {
  if (size < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");

  T[] result = new T[size];

  // You may put any special cases here, e.g. if you want empty strings instead of nulls
  // uncomment the exerp:
  //if (typeof(T) == typeof(String)) {
  //  for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i)
  //    result[i] = (T) ((Object) "");
  //   
  //  return result;  
  //}

  // If default value is null, instances should be created 
  // (if we manage to find out how to do it)
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, default(T))) {
    // Do we have a constructor by default (public one and without parameters)?
    ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

    // If do, let's create instances
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, ci))
      for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i)
        result[i] = (T) (ci.Invoke(new Object[] { }));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Test cases:

```
  // int is a structore, its default value is 0, so i = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  int[] i = CreateArray<int>(5);

  // String has no String() constructor, so s[] = [null, null, null, null, null]
  String[] s = CreateArray<String>(5); 

  // Button has Button() constructor, so b[] contains buttons 
  Button[] b = CreateArray<Button>(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following code

```
public class TypeClass
{
    public static T[] CreateArray<T>(int arrayLength) // using T[] would save you from type-casting
        where T : new()     // <-- Constrain to types with a default constructor
    {
        T[] t = new T[arrayLength];
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++)
            t[j] = new T();
        return t;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int [] intArray = TypeClass.CreateArray<int>(5);
        string [] stringArray = TypeClass.CreateArray<string>(5);
        Point [] pointArray = TypeClass.CreateArray<Point>(5);
        MyCustomClass [] myCustomClassArray = TypeClass.CreateArray<MyCustomClass>(5);
    }
}
```

This would work for all `Primitive` and `class` types which have `default` constructor defined.